# Mysql - Error 1726 (HY000) at line...: Storage engine 'InnoDB' does not support system tables

Tags: mysql, raspberry-pi, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

I am trying to export a database without data from mysql 8 to myqsl 5.7 and I am getting the following error:

> Error 1726 (HY000) at line...: Storage engine 'InnoDB' does not support system tables. [mysql.columns_priv]

The mysql 5.7 server is on a raspberry pi 3 b+, if that is of any significance.

To create the dump i did this:

> mysqldump -u root -p --no-data --all-databases > all_databases.sql

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do not export the **`mysql`** database. That is the database MYSQL uses to manage itself. It changes often and will definitely have changed a LOT between mysql5.7 and mysql8. _Also it is a MYISAM database, so not sure how you have made it into a INNODB database

Comment: Specify only those databases which you need to transfer really.

Comment: Only use `--all-databases` when you are doing a backup that will only ever be restored to the exact same version of MySQL

Comment: Major changes happened with `information_schema` between 5.7 and 8.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only use `--all-databases` when you are doing a backup that will only ever be restored to the exact same version of MySQL
- RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0):

If you did something like this then you don't have any option if you uninstalled mysql 8 after you took backup.

What you can do is first take backup with --all-databases for fresh 5.7 mysql. Then restore from mysql 8 dump. At the end again restore from 5.7 mysql original dump you took first.

```
mysqldump -uroot -p<password> --all-databases > mysql_5.7_default.sql
mysql -uroot -p<password> < dump_from_mysql_8.sql
mysql -uroot -p<password> < mysql_5.7_default.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `--all-databases`, you can exclude system databases and use `--databases` to pass to `mysqldump` only application databases:

```bash
$DUMPFILE=/tmp/mysqldump.sql
# first list all databases. column will remove table outlines. tail will ignore first line which is always "Databases"
ALL_DATABASES=$(
  mysql --raw \
    --user="$USER" --password="$PASSWORD" \
    --host="$HOST" \
    --execute='show databases;' \
    | column -t | tail -n +2
)
# using comm -23 you can compare two sets in bash and take the difference
DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE=(information_schema mysql performance_schema phpmyadmin sys tmp)
DATABASES_TO_BACKUP=$(comm -23 <(echo "$ALL_DATABASES"  | tr ' ' '\n') <(echo "${DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n'))

# the resulting DATABASES_TO_BACKUP will be the list of databases excluding the list DATABASES_TO_EXCLUDE. Note that ${DATABASES_TO_BACKUP[@]} must be without double quotes because we need word splitting in order for --databases argument to work
mysqldump \
  --user="$USER" --password="$PASSWORD" \
  --host="$HOST" \
  --databases ${DATABASES_TO_BACKUP[@]} >> "$DUMPFILE"
```